# Monitoring the Activities of Android Devices

Tags: android

I want to develop an android application which allow to me to track and save into an online database the following information:

- Incoming and outgoing call
- Incoming and outgoing SMS
- Keystrokes typed by keyboard

Questions:

1. How can I run my application in the background (must use service or thread)?
2. Is it possible to got incoming or outgoing calls with details 
   (phone number, date of call, call duration, etc.)?
3. Is it possible to got incoming or outgoing messages with details 
   (destination/origin number , message content)?
4. Is it possible to got all keystrokes typed by keyboard?
5. Do I need root access to do this?

Comment: Looks like spyware to me. The call log is readable, also the sms, but the keylogger part is not feasible unless you create your own keyboard. I don't think you'll need root, but the user should grant the permissions. And in case you used a bg service, then a launcher activity must be provided for newer OS versions to launch the service the 1st time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I run my application in the background (must use service or thread)?

Use a service

> Is it possible to got incoming or outgoing calls with details (phone number, date of call, call duration, etc.)?

Yes.

> Is it possible to got incoming or outgoing messages with details (destination/origin number , message content)?

For incoming there is official SDK support. For outgoing, there are only unofficial methods.

> Is it possible to got all keystrokes typed by keyboard?

This is impossible, unless you also wrote the keyboard app being used.

> Do I need root access to do this?

No.